# store file with invalid characters

Tags: shell, zsh, character-encoding, ascii

Some files we get from a customer could not be processed properly because they were declared as US-ASCII but contained invalid characters. In order to validate a software fix, I am trying to copy several lines from the original  file to a new file. The original files are quite large and I only need a couple of lines.

The original line looks like this in gedit `003002002002\D4M`, the `\D4` part in red and I get a warning about invalid characters. on the console, the original line looks like this: `003002002002�M`

I have tried to pipe the files through head & tail, but the resulting file contains a 'fixed' character instead of the invalid one.

`head -n 449025 invalid.txt | tail > invalid_short.txt`

the line looks like this if I cat the resulting file: `003002002002�M`
but if i open the resulting file with gedit it looks like this: `003002002002ÔM` and there are no invalid characters

I have tried to select the lines in gedit and save them as a new file, but I only get a representation of the invalid char, not the original one. It looks like this with cat and gedit (no invalid char warning, no red): `003002002002\D4M`

Looks like I am missing something simple, but I have no idea what.

Thank you

Ubuntu 16.04, zsh

Comment: What you show appears to be UTF or similar but `head` and `tail` don't change the data, which is why I don't post this as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I have assumed UTF at first, but when reading the file as UTF, the reader broke with `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1`. It does not break if I advise the codec to replace malformed input with a null byte. `file -bi` returns `us-ascii`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`head` or `tail` will not *fix*/*change* the character.

What probably happens is that `gedit` tries to guess the encoding of the file based on the first few bytes. When that 0xD4 is far within the file, `gedit` guesses the file is in ASCII or UTF-8 and complains when it sees that 0xD4 byte that is invalid in either ASCII or UTF-8.

While for the second shorter file, since 0xD4 is near the beginning of the file, `gedit` guesses the character set is some 8 bit character set (probably iso8859-1 where 0xD4 is Ô).

So your:

```
head -n 449025 invalid.txt | tail > invalid_short.txt
```

method is correct. If you run `sed -n l` on both files, you'll see in both cases something like `003002002002\324M`. And with `hd`: `30 30 33 30 30 32 30 30  32 30 30 32 d4 4d        |003002002002.M|`.

Comment: even simpler than I hoped for :) Thanks Stephane